# OnClickListener error in onCreate method

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android. i use this code but when run app emulator show exception.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnpredef = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
    btnpredef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            progressbar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","LOADING...");
            progressbar.setCancelable(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Debug catch error from **new OnClickListener()**.

thanks to help me.

logCat :

```
10-05 15:05:01.499: D/AndroidRuntime(383): Shutting down VM
10-05 15:05:01.499: W/dalvikvm(383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app007/com.example.app007.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at com.example.app007.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-05 15:05:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(383):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where is the reference to the progressDialog ?

Comment: Can you post the logCat error report?

Comment: i test [^](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-solve-must-override-superclass.html) and [^](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html) and other search in sites

Comment: By the way what is the error or Exception you are getting ?

Comment: @RajeevNB define those in public public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private ProgressDialog progressbar;
 private AnimationDrawable myAnimation;

Comment: @AndroSelva in logCat don't show any error or warnings

Comment: @RajeevNB at create app emuator show forceclose msg

Comment: @AndroSelva i restart adt and loCat show many.this is one of them: 10-05 15:00:08.848: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.app007.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)

Comment: this is not enough. post all the red colored lines. Add it to your quesiton

Comment: @1mohammadi.ir remove android.R..... and do it R.id.... simply. check my answer I have same exception as you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove android from

```
Button btnpredef = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

and do it

```
Button btnpredef = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

make a refrence

```
ProgressDialog progressBar;
```

and then add this line

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
```

before

```
 progressbar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","LOADING...");
```

And add this line in last

```
progressBar.show();
```

Here is a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/) which can help you.

Comment: remove android from findviewbyid

Answer (score 0):

just replace new `View.OnClickListener()` with `new OnClickListener()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button btnpredef = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnpredef.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        progressbar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "","LOADING...");
        progressbar.setCancelable(true);
        progressbar.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I do this but still exception eccured

Comment: just check your manifest file. whether you have declare all activity names or not

Comment: manufest has mainactivity : <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
```

`ProgressDialog progressbar; <----`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnpredef = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
    btnpredef.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener()   <---
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            progressbar = ProgressDialog.show(v.getContext(), "","LOADING..."); <--
            progressbar.setCancelable(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you have not declared activity name into manifest file properly.
Check your package name and activity name into manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I replace **android.R.id.button1** to **R.id.button1**
thanks @Pain